# Inherited method returning no data

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

When subclassing a base class, an inherited method is not working as expected.

I've broken my module into a couple of pieces (sorry if this difficult to follow) all in a directory named `Lan`.

in `Lan/__init__.py` I have:

```
from Bridge import Bridge
from Ethernet import Ethernet

from BaseInterface import BaseInterface


def IfCtl(iftype):
    for cls in BaseInterface.__subclasses__():
        if iftype in cls.iftypes():
            return cls()
    raise ValueError
```

In `Lan/Bridge.py`

```
from Lan.BaseInterface import BaseInterface

class Bridge(BaseInterface):
    def __init__(self):
        BaseInterface.__init__(self)

    @staticmethod
    def iftypes():
        return ['br', 'bridge']

    def up(self):
        return 'Bringing up Bridge'

    def down(self):
        return 'Bringing down Bridge'
```

and finally in `Lan/BaseInterface.py`:

```
from time import sleep

class IfaceNotImplementedError(NotImplementedError):
    def __init__(self, methodName):
        self.methodName = methodName
    def __str__(self):
        return "Method %s must be subclassed" % self.methodName

class BaseInterface(object):
    @staticmethod
    def iftypes(): return ['']

    def up(self): raise IfaceNotImplementedError('up()')

    def down(self): raise IfaceNotImplementedError('down()')

    def restart(self, delay = 1.0):
        self.down()
        sleep(delay)
        self.up()
```

Everything seems to work as expected except the `restart()` method inherited from `BaseInterface`.  The method appears to run because there is a pause when I run it, but I returns no data. I'd expect to see the text returned by the overwritten `up()` and `down()` methods.

```
>>> from Lan import IfCtl
>>> InterFace = IfCtl('br')
>>> print InterFace.down()
Bringing down Bridge
>>> print InterFace.up()
Bringing up Bridge
>>> print InterFace.restart()
None
>>>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `restart()` method does not return anything.  If you want it to carry the return value of up you need the last line to read `return self.up()`.  Otherwise, it will always return `None` like it is now - the default return for any function that does not have an explicit return value.

Comment: @tMC - it happens.  That's probably the best thing about SO - getting someone else's eyes on the problem.  That fixes it more often than anything else, IMHO.

Answer (score 2):

You are not returning from `restart`

You either need to change:

```
def up(self):
    return 'Bringing up Bridge'
```

to

```
def up(self):
    print 'Bringing up Bridge'
```

or change:

```
def restart(self, delay = 1.0):
    self.down()
    sleep(delay)
    self.up()
```

to

```
def restart(self, delay = 1.0):
    vals = []
    vals.append(self.down())
    sleep(delay)
    vals.append(self.up())
    return vals
```

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
def restart(self, delay = 1.0):
    self.down()
    sleep(delay)
    self.up()
```

to:

```
def restart(self, delay = 1.0):
    print self.down()
    sleep(delay)
    print self.up()
```